# Download and print multiple files/links at once?

Tags: firefox, printing, download, browser-addons

I have a list of links to **lots** (I mean hundreds) of HTML-pages with one bill each.

How can I automate **printing all of those pages at once** with a printer (no PDF)?

I think I saw an add-on for Firefox once, that lets you download all links in a selection at once, but I cannot remember.

Also I need to print them automatically after downloading.

Comment: The [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) plugin for Firefox may help you with the download step.

Comment: DownThemAll! plugin for Firefox just helps with downloading, but How can I print them all at once then?

Answer (score 1):

If they are HTML-pages with bills it is best to print them to a PDF. You can use something like [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) to print to PDF. *You can skip this part if you don't need to have a digital copy. You can also print directly to a physical printer in the process below*.

For the printing process itself:

Under "Internet Explorer" you have, in the print-dialog under options, the option to "Print all linked documents". Use this with care. It will print **all** linked pages. (including disclaimer, info etc.)

For Firefox i only found a plugin which prints all open tabs. With [Universal Print](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/universal-print/) you can print all open tabs (or selected ones). You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Left click on all your documents opening them in a background tab after which you can print them all with Universal Print.

As i said the printing goes to PDF-files (downloaded in a folder) after which you can select them all in the folder and with Right-click/Print print them all.

Comment: PDFs is not an option, I need all those with one click or so on paper (unfortunately)

Comment: Then you can skip the PDF-creation and just print them directly to a physical printer. I thought you wanted to "download" them so you would have a digital copy. But printing to a printer instead of PDF is just as easy.

Comment: If printing directly then be careful with the IE method because that prints **all** linked documents directly. Including little links to info-pages etc. So i would recommend opening them with the Ctrl+Click and then printing the tabs with "universal print".